# Where to find webpack.config.js?I want to change webpack configuration mode to 'development'.My system is linux ,i installed 'firebase' using 'npm'

Tags: firebase, webpack

I tried "webpack --mode=development" but it threw an error. [screen shot of the terminal when i tried this command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AxzP.png)

[my 'firebase project directory'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3crfM.png)

[@webpack directory under node_modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFTMl.png)

[webpack and webpack-cli directory under node_modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1g5t.png)

[node and npm versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMG60.png)

i was trying to learn "Firebase" from official documentation and yt video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQvOAnNvcNQ&t=89s) posted there
when i tried 'module bundler'section , i was unable to do that...